# Page number birt

Tags: birt

I have a problem with birt, version 4.13.0:
I have a report with 4 pages, and I want to display the page number and the total page number in master page's footer, but the report displays always page 1 of 1.

This is the java code I use to elaborate the report:

public byte[] generatePDFReport(String reportName, HttpServletResponse response,
HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> inputMap) throws Exception {
ServletContext sc = request.getSession().getServletContext();
BirtEngineFactory factory = new BirtEngineFactory() ;
IReportEngine birtEngine = factory.getObject();
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:reports/" +reportName);

```
            //IReportRunnable runnable = birtEngine.openReportDesign("reports/" + reportName);
            //IReportRunnable runnable = birtEngine.openReportDesign("C:\\Users\\nicol\\git\\ergo-toolkit-be-nicola\\src\\main\\resources\\reports\\new_report.rptdesign");
            //IReportRunnable runnable = birtEngine.openReportDesign("C:\\Users\\nicol\\git\\ergo-toolkit-be-nicola\\src\\main\\resources\\reports\\new_report.rptdesign");
            IReportRunnable runnable = birtEngine.openReportDesign(resource.getURI().getPath());
            IRunAndRenderTask runAndRenderTask = birtEngine.createRunAndRenderTask(runnable);
            if (null != inputMap && inputMap.size() > 0) {
                runAndRenderTask.getAppContext().putAll(inputMap);
            }
            //runAndRenderTask.setPageHandler(new IPageHandler())
            
            response.setContentType(birtEngine.getMIMEType("pdf"));
            IRenderOption options = new RenderOption();
            PDFRenderOption pdfRenderOption = new PDFRenderOption(options);
            /*pdfRenderOption.setOption( IPDFRenderOption.FIT_TO_PAGE, Boolean.FALSE );
            pdfRenderOption.setOption( IPDFRenderOption.PAGEBREAK_PAGINATION_ONLY, Boolean.FALSE );*/
            pdfRenderOption.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, Boolean.TRUE);
            pdfRenderOption.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.REPAGINATE_FOR_PDF, Boolean.FALSE);
            pdfRenderOption.setOutputFormat("pdf");
            runAndRenderTask.setRenderOption(pdfRenderOption);
            runAndRenderTask.getAppContext().put(EngineConstants.APPCONTEXT_PDF_RENDER_CONTEXT, request);
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream outs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                /*options.setOutputStream(outs);
                pdfRenderOption.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());*/
                pdfRenderOption.setOutputStream(outs);
                runAndRenderTask.run();
                return outs.toByteArray();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
            } finally {
                runAndRenderTask.close();
            }
        }
```

can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you open the report in the all-in-one-designer and choose Run Report -> As PDF?